# Pyspark: Split and select part of the string column values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I select the characters or file path after the `Dev\”` and `dev\`  from the column in a spark DF?

**Sample rows of the pyspark column:**

```
\\D\Dev\johnny\Desktop\TEST
\\D\Dev\matt\Desktop\TEST\NEW
\\D\Dev\matt\Desktop\TEST\OLD\TEST
\\E\dev\peter\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
```

**Expected Output**

```
johnny\Desktop\TEST
matt\Desktop\TEST\NEW
matt\Desktop\TEST\OLD\TEST
peter\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
```

I tried to use the code below.

```
df = df.withColumn(
        "sub_path",
        F.element_at(F.split(F.col("path"), "Dev\\\\"), -1)
    )
```

It's only giving the part correct results that I want.
Appreciate someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modification `[Dd]` matches both upper and lower case `d`.

```py
df = df.withColumn(
        "sub_path",
        F.element_at(F.split(F.col("path"), "[Dd]ev\\\\"), -1)
    )
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to choose by the number of backslashes? In this case, after 4th backslash, we choose the rest of the string? When we have large numbers of rows with different charactors.

Comment: Please add this as another question with sample data and expected results to test possible solutions so that we may look at this also.

Comment: I have added a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024095/pyspark-select-part-of-the-stringfile-path-column-values Thank you for the support