# Pyspark: Select part of the string(file path) column values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[Pyspark: Split and select part of the string column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69022962/pyspark-split-and-select-part-of-the-string-column-values/69023437?noredirect=1#comment121988944_69023437)

How can I select the characters or file path after the 4th(from left) backslash from the column in a spark DF?

**Sample rows of the pyspark column:**

```
\\D\Dev\johnny\Desktop\TEST
\\D\Dev\matt\Desktop\TEST\NEW
\\D\Dev\matt\Desktop\TEST\OLD\TEST
\\E\dev\peter\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
\\K924\prod\ums\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
\\LE345\jskx\rfk\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
.
.
.
\\ls53\f7sn3\vso\hsk\mwq\sdsf\kse
```

**Expected Output**

```
johnny\Desktop\TEST
matt\Desktop\TEST\NEW
matt\Desktop\TEST\OLD\TEST
peter\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
ums\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
rfk\Desktop\RUN\SUBFOLDER\New
.
.
.
vso\hsk\mwq\sdsf\kse
```

My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69022962/pyspark-split-and-select-part-of-the-string-column-values/69023437?noredirect=1#comment121988944_69023437) led to this new question.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a regular expression in `regexp_replace` eg.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('sub_path',F.regexp_replace("path","^\\\\\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\\",""))
```

you may also be more flexible with this solution eg.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
no_of_slashes=4 # number of slashes to consider here

# we build the regular expression by repeating `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\\"`
# NB. We subtract 2 since we start with the frst 2 slashes
df = df.withColumn('sub_path',F.regexp_replace("path","^\\\\\\\\"+("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\\"*(no_of_slashes-2)),""))
```

Let me know if this works for you.